# How can i get the position or the anchor from detected object using Azure Object Anchors

Tags: azure, position, hololens, azure-object-anchors

I want to get the anchor or the position of the detected object with Azure Object Anchors.
Can you give me some examples or the method I can use?

I tried with the Microsoft example that detects the object from reality but I can't find a solution to get the position from that object.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the post.  For getting the position, here is a link that shows how to do that from the Object Anchors github that was confirmed and user was able to use successfully:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-object-anchors/issues/35

"The short answer is yes - use the ObjectModel.OriginToCenterTransform property to relate origin-relative content to the center of the detected object instance."